# Getting constant values from another controller inside my own controller

Tags: extensions

I would like to be able to access the constants defined in:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php

const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT  = 'contacts/email/recipient_email';
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER     = 'contacts/email/sender_email_identity';
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE   = 'contacts/email/email_template';
const XML_PATH_ENABLED          = 'contacts/contacts/enabled';
```

I want to be able to get these values to use in my own controller. How would I go about this?

I have already created my custom controller in my extension. It works fine.

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Contacts').DS.'IndexController.php');

class Cti_Enhancedform_EnhancedformController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {



    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with every constant:

```
Mage_Contacts_IndexController:: XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT
```

Comment: Exceptionally short and unbeatable precise answer :)